# Getting EditText value from ListView works... Sometimes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

So I have a ListView with custom Cells that have an EditText in them. I put together a function that is called on request, which spits out a nice list of all the values of each of the Edit Texts. All the cells are created from a static list, and they are all exactly the same.
**The problem is, the first 7 cells work fine with the code below**, and then it crashes:

```
ListView l = (ListView) CartPage.this.findViewById(R.id.cartItems);
// total_item_count is equal to the int 11, which is how many cells there are.
for(int i=0;i<total_item_count-1;i++){
    View view=l.getChildAt(i);
    System.out.println("("+i+"/"+total_item_count+")");
    EditText editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.product_count);
    String string=editText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(i+": "+string);

}
```

Here is my error log:

```
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3617)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17397)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5167)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3612)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    ... 11 more
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    at com.venuevip.android.CartPage.updateCart(CartPage.java:305)
02-17 06:44:17.540: E/AndroidRuntime(29086):    ... 14 more
```

I have tried cleaning my project 10 times now, to no avail.

**Edit: Discovered that it only works for the number of items displayed on screen (So when you flip it into landscape and 3 items are shown, it works only for the first 3).**

Comment: What's the 305th line of your `CartPage.java` file? It would also be necessary to post surrounding relevant code, so we know what are you doing.

Comment: My comment is not relevant to the original question, but I really think your for-loop is not correct. It should be `for(int i=0;i<total_item_count;i++) {`.

Comment: @nKn EditText editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.product_count);

Comment: @trylimits Yep, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListView l = (ListView) CartPage.this.findViewById(R.id.cartItems);
EditText editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.product_count);
String string;
// total_item_count is equal to the int 11, which is how many cells there are.
for(int i=0;i<total_item_count-1;i++){
    View view=l.getChildAt(i);
    System.out.println("("+i+"/"+total_item_count+")");

    string=editText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(i+": "+string);

}
```

Declare edittext instance outside of for loop

Comment: Tried it out, and it worked great! Removed view.findViewById, and changed it to findViewById (Since view is not yet defined), and then it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: View view=l.getChildAt(i) what is the purpose of this line ? view is not used

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't iterate the views in a `ListView` and assume that it actually contains a separate view for each item in the list. It doesn't, `ListView` recycles views and only swaps the data according to the `ListAdapter` when scrolling through.

Instead you should iterate your data in your `ListAdapter`, but that means that you will most likely have to modify your adapter code to save the text in the `EditTexts` somewhere when they are edited.